# Spark Aggregator on sorted Window never uses merge - is this reliable?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator` to implement custom logic on a series of rows. I have noticed that the `merge()` function is *never* called when the Aggregator is applied to an ordered window with rows between `unboundedPreceding` and `currentRow`, i.e. the aggregation behavior is entirely determined by how new elements are added to the latest reduction, `reduce()`.

If `merge()` is indeed never called in this case, UDAFs would be a great tool to integrate arbitrary custom logic on large partitions of ordered rows; see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83666/foss-data-stack-to-perform-complex-custom-logic-on-billions-of-ordered-rows. However, I cannot find this being mentioned in the Spark documentation or the Spark issue tracker, and hence I am wondering if it is safe to use in this way - specifically for custom algorithms that don't allow for a `merge()`-like operation.

Below is some code specifically to test this behavior. I have locally checked the observation with a set of 300 million rows and partitioning based on three columns (each partition having a few million rows), and the observation holds up.

##### timestampdata.csv

```
category,eventTime
a,240
a,489
b,924
a,890
b,563
a,167
a,134
b,600
b,901
```

##### OrderedProcessing.scala

```scala
object OrderedProcessing {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val checkOrderingUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udaf[Int, OrderProcessingInfo, OrderProcessingInfo](CheckOrdering)

    val df_data = spark.read
      .options(Map("inferSchema" -> "true", "delimiter" -> ",", "header" -> "true"))
      .csv("./timestampdata.csv")

    val df_checked = df_data
      .withColumn("orderProcessingInfo",
        checkOrderingUdf.apply($"eventTime").over(
          Window.partitionBy("category").orderBy("eventTime")
            .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)))
      .select($"category", $"eventTime",
        $"orderProcessingInfo".getItem("processedAllInOrder").alias("processedAllInOrder"),
        $"orderProcessingInfo".getItem("haveUsedReduce").alias("haveUsedReduce"),
        $"orderProcessingInfo".getItem("haveUsedMerge").alias("haveUsedMerge"))

    df_checked.groupBy("processedAllInOrder", "haveUsedReduce", "haveUsedMerge").count().show()
  }
}
```

##### OrderProcessingInfo.scala

```scala
case class OrderProcessingInfo(latestTime: Int, processedAllInOrder: Boolean, haveUsedReduce: Boolean, haveUsedMerge: Boolean)
```

##### CheckOrdering.scala

```scala
object CheckOrdering extends Aggregator[Int, OrderProcessingInfo, OrderProcessingInfo] {
  override def zero = OrderProcessingInfo(0, true, false, false)

  override def reduce(agg: OrderProcessingInfo, e: Int) = OrderProcessingInfo(
    latestTime = e, processedAllInOrder = agg.processedAllInOrder & (e >= agg.latestTime),
    haveUsedReduce = true, haveUsedMerge = agg.haveUsedMerge
  )
  
  override def merge(agg1: OrderProcessingInfo, agg2: OrderProcessingInfo) = OrderProcessingInfo(
    latestTime = agg1.latestTime.max(agg2.latestTime),
    processedAllInOrder = agg1.processedAllInOrder & agg2.processedAllInOrder & (agg2.latestTime >= agg1.latestTime),
    haveUsedReduce = agg1.haveUsedReduce | agg2.haveUsedReduce,
    haveUsedMerge = true
  )

  override def finish(agg: OrderProcessingInfo) = agg
  override def bufferEncoder: Encoder[OrderProcessingInfo] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[OrderProcessingInfo])
  override def outputEncoder: Encoder[OrderProcessingInfo] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[OrderProcessingInfo])
}
```

##### output

```bash
+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----+
|processedAllInOrder|haveUsedReduce|haveUsedMerge|count|
+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----+
|               true|          true|        false|    9|
+-------------------+--------------+-------------+-----+
```